# Is there a reason why DKIM signs every mail twice

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, amavis

I've configured my postfix/amavisd-new/spam-assassin setup after this tutorial https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/DKIM. But now the problem is that all mails I send are double signed with two DKMI Headers, one before and one after the mail is sent to amavisd-new. How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Possible problem is using opendkim and rspamd, when rspamd enables the dkim-signing module ... :( happened to me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to disable milter processing after amavis, add to your `master.cf` in the after-amavis section

```
127.0.0.1:10025 inet    n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
[....]
-o smtpd_milters=
```

if you want to run the milter after amavis, set the `smtpd_milters=` configuration option in `main.cf` to an empty string and add the `inet:localhost:8891` configuration to master.cf  instead:

```
-o smtpd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
```

Comment: Should this solution also work with spamassassin? (asking because it failed on my server)

Comment: Which is best practice? After Amavis?  
@Lexib0y - spamassassin is run via amavis(-new), normally. So, the answer is yes. Try 'after amavis is run' in this answer. Works for me, anyway.